# DispatcherTimer keeps firing after I've stopped it. C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm having trouble with the following code.  I have some code that calls `SetTimer()` and expects the user to respond before `interval` is reached (in
millisecs).  The calling code inherit these funtions.  If the user responds, then `StopTimer()` is called, info is displayed, `StartTimer()` is called, and the user is expected to respond again within the `interval` time period.  This continues until the user fails in an answer or takes too long (goes past the `interval`).

The problem is the timers don't stop.  They keep repeating even after I've stopped them, set their `Tick` event to `null` (by the `-=` method), and left its scope.  I even get new storage with a new `DispatcherTimer` (I've done this both using the old one and a new one each time).  I can't get the old `Timer` to go away.

What am I doing wrong?

```
using Windows.UI.XAML;

public DispatcherTimer GameTimer;

internal void SetTimer(int interval) 
{
    GameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    GameTimer.Tick += TimerCallback;
    GameTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,interval);
    GameTimer.Start();
}

internal void StopTimer() 
{
    GameTimer.Stop();
    try 
    {
        GameTimer.Tick -= TimerCallback;
    } catch {}
}

private void TimerCallback(object sender, object e) 
{
    StopTimer();
    // Other code
}
```

Thanks in advance,

-justin

Comment: `    } catch {}` is just bad practice.  Log or don't catch to be sure what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried using using `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`.  I'm running similar code with that and have no problems stopping it.  I'd try `Windows.UI.XAML.DispatchTimer` but don't have a windows 10 dev box.

Comment: I believe that in order to use `System.Windows.Threading` I have to have `WindowsBase` installed as a reference, which I do not believe is possible for a UWP app, or at least I haven't discovered how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the timer by using the sender object, not the actual public timer object:

```
private void TimerCallback(object sender, object e) {
    (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
    // Other code
}
```

Comment: I also need to stop the timer from the outside--when the user answers within the time limit. So outside code needs to call StopTimer() and have it work.  This didn't fix it.  But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could do something like:

```
// in your class
private bool _allowExecution = false;
```

Then whenever you start the time set `_allowExecution = true;` and when you stop the timer, simply add `_allowExecution = false;`

The last thing will be to add a simply boolean condition on your timer execute: `if (_allowExecute) //do your stuff here`

Answer (score 0):

Because you initialize a new `DispatcherTimer` everytime call `SetTimer(int interval)`. You must stop the old `DispatcherTimer` instance before initialize a new one.

```
internal void SetTimer(int interval) 
{
    StopTimer();
    GameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    GameTimer.Tick += TimerCallback;
    GameTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,interval);
    GameTimer.Start();
}

internal void StopTimer() 
{
    if(GameTimer != null)
    {
        GameTimer.Stop();
        GameTimer.Tick -= TimerCallback;
        GameTimer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways, initializing a new 'DispatcherTimer' or reusing one setup when the class is first setup.  It doesn't seem to matter:  'GameTimer.Stop()' isn't working.  I copied this code in precisely and it didn't work either.

Comment: @JustinBurns I notice you make GameTimer public, does somewhere change it? you can create a new blank app and just copy the code snippet, if it works fine, you may need go back and double check your project.

Comment: I did as you suggested and made an app with two buttons, a textbox, and the above timer.  Each button displayed its name in the textbox when clicked on and the timer displayed 'Time' when it triggered.  Everything worked as it should.  This means something in the mass of the rest of the program is causing my issue.  At least I know the timer should work, I'm using it correctly, and there is something in the mass of the rest of the app that is causing the issue.  Thanks for the help.